# C# find T4MVC function calls by regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm converting my ASP.NET MVC application to Core!
One of my problem is converting 'Url.Action(MVC.Account.ResetPasswordCode())' to 'Url.Action("ResetPasswordCode","Account")'.
I need to find all 'MVC.Foo.Bar()' or  'MVC.Foo.Bar.Baz()' matches by regular expressions.

I have tried this patterns in regex.

```
"(MVC.)(.*?)(\\(\\))"
```

But result is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: It matches the string above, [look here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28MVC%5c.%29%28.*%3f%29%28%5c%28%5c%29%29&i=Url.Action%28MVC.Account.ResetPasswordCode%28%29%29). I escaped the dot since you seem to want to match it as a literal symbol.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew: Thanks, yes it is my mistake.